# mod rewrite rule for searching a string from url and replace just domain name of that url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to create rewrite rule for .htaccess.
for example: 
In url if `Itemid=702` is found then I only I want to redirect to below

Original URL is:

```
www.dashboard.example.com/comp/temp/health/appt?Itemid=702
```

Redirect to:

```
www.admin.example.com/comp/temp/health/appt?Itemid=702
```

I have tried with below condition, but it doesn't work.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} Itemid=702$
RewriteRule .* http://admin.example.com [R,L]
```

How can I create this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, change the rule to:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} Itemid=702 [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://admin.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply, does it work for all url which contains Itemid=702 ...?

Comment: Yes, it does exactly that. Is that what you want?

Comment: Hi, the url is redirecting, but the page is not displaying. its sowing below error "The page isn't redirecting properly". while its going in infinite loop.
pls help.

Comment: I am getting url same like i want, but the issue is it's shows an error "The page isn't redirecting properly" and going in infinite loop.